# C++ hashing algorithm

Tags: c++, hash, sha1

I have the following algoritm (based on SHA-1 hash function implementation).  It produces the hash of "abc". The result is the unsigned `char*` digest.

```
#define BYTES "abce"
SHA1* sha1 = new SHA1();
sha1->addBytes( BYTES, strlen( BYTES ) );
unsigned char* digest = sha1->getDigest();
```

I would like to rehash the result digest. I m doing this in the following way but does not work. Is `char* S` defined something different from `#define BYTES "abce"` ?

```
char* S = reinterpret_cast<char*>(digest);
sha1 = new SHA1();
sha1->addBytes( S, strlen( S ) );           
unsigned char* digest1 = sha1->getDigest();
```

Answer (score 5):

Do not ever use `strlen` on anything but a C-style string.

```
          sha1->addBytes( S, strlen( S ) );
```

That makes no sense. You probably want 20, the size of a SHA digest.

Comment: Along the same lines, I would suggest not using `strlen()` for the original string either. Either declare it as `const char BYTES[] = "abc";`, then use `sizeof(BYTES)`, or use a `std::string`. If you handle random binary data, use a separate length attribute, or (even better), go for a `std::vector`.